# UILabel scales only for certain text lengths

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have a custom `UIView` containing a `UILabel` and a `UISwitch`. The switch and the label are constrained to be next to each other with their center-y equal and their sides matching the sides of the parent (with a margin). The label is constrained to connect with the top and bottom of its parent (again, plus margin) with its number of lines set to `0` so it can scale as large as it needs to be to fit all the text, using word wrapping as the line break mode. I have a bunch of these custom views below each other in a vertical `UIStackView` with alignment and distribution set to `fill`. The stack view itself is positioned inside a scroll view which is constrained to all sides of the root view (which scrolls as expected). Here's a screenshot of the situation that also shows my problem:

[image: Custom views in UIStackView]

I've added a red background to the label in the custom view to show its boundaries. Separator views are added between the custom views. The problem becomes apparent in the second custom view in this screenshot. Its label text is actually `WordOne WordTwo WordThree WordFour`, but for whatever reason the text is wrapped without the label / parent increasing their size to contain it. Adding an extra word, as in the view below it, suddenly does scale the label to show all of its lines. I've set compression resistance to `UILayoutPriorityRequired` for both the label and the parent, to no avail. I have a workaround involving a `layoutSubviews` override with a manual calculation of the label size, but I'd prefer both understanding what's going on and of course avoiding having to use a hack. Can anybody shed some light on this behavior?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the text is set properly? If it was a problem with the label height not changing properly, you should see "WordThree" anyway. If it **is** being set, try using `Debug View Hierarchy` to see if there are any constraint issues.

Comment: One can never be 100% certain of anything, but yes, I am. My first thought was the same as yours: why isn't at least `WordThree` showing up? But I think this relates to the different `UILabel` word wrapping in later iOS versions (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751185/uilabel-line-breaks-too-early-on-ios-11) which forces the last line to have at least two words on it. This is why `WordThree` all of a sudden does fit on the first line in the other views.

Comment: Ah, yes, the "no orphans word-wrap feature" as of iOS 11 is why we don't see `WordThree` on your second example line, but that doesn't explain the failed sizing. I'm adding an answer with a quick test which also sees the "no orphans" effect, but ***does not*** show the same failed sizing results you're getting.

Comment: Actually, since it doesn't explain what you're getting, it's not appropriate for an answer here. So, here's my result: https://imgur.com/a/t5c3AQK and here's the code: https://pastebin.com/GtBqUE02

Comment: "no orphans word-wrap", good to know it has a name for future reference. Don't you love it when someone else tries the same thing and cannot reproduce your problem? :P

Comment: I realize now that I forgot to mention that the stack view is inside a scroll view, which does scroll as I'd expect - minus, of course, this label sizing problem.

Comment: Being embedded in a scroll view shouldn't have any effect... can you reproduce this in a [mcve]?

Comment: I will, once I get to it. If I had to create a minimal repro for every weird bug I encountered in the last three weeks or so I wouldn't be able to do any other work for another three, unfortunately. I was hoping the cause for this would be obvious to someone, but I guess that isn't the case.

Comment: I updated my sample code at https://pastebin.com/GtBqUE02 to embed the stack view in a (short) scroll view, along with the resulting screen-cap https://imgur.com/a/t5c3AQK ... still not experiencing the issue.